# Not able to display data in gridview using WebMethod with Jquery Ajax getting Internal Server Error?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to display data in Gridview using WebMethod in Jquery and Ajax. I am using stored procedure for pagination in SQL Server database and return per page data. When page is rendered on browser No Data is displayed but alert() function of jquery is fired stating that I am getting error. On clicking inspect element I have seen that error is- "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500(Internal Server Error)"

**Aspx Page**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
<style type="text/css">
    body
    {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 10pt;
    }
    .Pager span
    {
        text-align: center;
        color: #999;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 20px;
        background-color: #A1DCF2;
        margin-right: 3px;
        line-height: 150%;
        border: 1px solid #3AC0F2;
    }
    .Pager a
    {
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 20px;
        background-color: #3AC0F2;
        color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #3AC0F2;
        margin-right: 3px;
        line-height: 150%;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ASPSnippets_Pager.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        GetABC(1);
    });
    $(".Pager .page").live("click", function () {
        GetABC(parseInt($(this).attr('page')));
    });
    function GetABC(pageIndex) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ABC.aspx/GetABC",
            data: '{pageIndex: ' + pageIndex + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert("Failure");
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    }

    function OnSuccess(response) {

        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
        var xml = $(xmlDoc);
        var xyz = xml.find("table1");
        var row = $("[id*=GridView1] tr:last-child").clone(true);
        $("[id*=GridView1] tr").not($("[id*=GridView1] tr:first-child")).remove();
        $.each(xyz, function () {
            var abc= $(this);
            $("td", row).eq(0).html($(this).find("XXX").text());
            $("td", row).eq(1).html($(this).find("XXX").text());
            $("td", row).eq(2).html($(this).find("XXX").text());
            $("td", row).eq(3).html($(this).find("XXX").text());
            $("td", row).eq(4).html($(this).find("XXX").text());
            $("td", row).eq(5).html($(this).find("XXX").text());
            $("td", row).eq(6).html($(this).find("XXX").text());
            $("td", row).eq(7).html($(this).find("XXX").text());
            $("[id*=GridView1]").append(row);
            row = $("[id*=GridView1] tr:last-child").clone(true);
        });
        var pager = xml.find("Pager");
        $(".Pager").ASPSnippets_Pager({
            ActiveCssClass: "current",
            PagerCssClass: "pager",
            PageIndex: parseInt(pager.find("PageIndex").text()),
            PageSize: parseInt(pager.find("PageSize").text()),
            RecordCount: parseInt(pager.find("RecordCount").text())
        });
    };
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        RowStyle-BackColor="#A1DCF2" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" 
        HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
    <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" HeaderText="XXX" DataField="XXX" />
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" HeaderText="XXX" DataField="XXX" />
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" HeaderText="XXX" DataField="XXX" />
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" HeaderText="XXX" DataField="XXX" />
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="200px" HeaderText="XXX" DataField="XXX" />
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" HeaderText="XXX" DataField="XXX" />
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="5px" HeaderText="XXX" DataField="XXX" />
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="5px" HeaderText="XXX" DataField="XXX" />
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <br />
    <div class="Pager"></div>
</asp:Content>
```

**CS page-**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Services;
public partial class ABC: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private static int PageSize = 10;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindGrid();
        }
    }
    private void BindGrid()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("xxx");
        dt.Columns.Add("xxx");
        dt.Columns.Add("xxx");
        dt.Columns.Add("xxx");
        dt.Columns.Add("xxx");
        dt.Columns.Add("xxx");
        dt.Columns.Add("xxx");
        dt.Columns.Add("xxx");
        dt.Rows.Add();
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetABC(int PageIndex)
    {
        string query = "[GetABC_Pager]";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageIndex", PageIndex);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageSize", PageSize);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@RecordCount", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        return GetData(cmd, PageIndex).GetXml();
    }
    private static DataSet GetData(SqlCommand cmd, int pageIndex)
    {
        string strConnstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnstring))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    sda.Fill(ds, "table1");
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable("Pager");
                    dt.Columns.Add("PageIndex");
                    dt.Columns.Add("PageSize");
                    dt.Columns.Add("RecordCount");
                    dt.Rows.Add();
                    dt.Rows[0]["PageIndex"] = pageIndex;
                    dt.Rows[0]["PageSize"] = PageSize;
                    dt.Rows[0]["RecordCount"] = cmd.Parameters["@RecordCount"].Value;
                    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
                    return ds;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On page load alert("Error") function is getting fired and with no data in gridview. Same code when I am running on my Localhost no error is showing, but when I am transferring the same file to my server I am getting this error. Please guide me where I am doing wrong, and do I need to do anything else. I have followed this article to develop this application- http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Retrieve-data-from-Database-and-display-on-page-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: have you added to `configuration key:myconnection` ? 
you can also enable tracing to view actual error occured.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94c55d08.aspx

Comment: @Dot_NETPro: Rendering is successful. After page is rendered on my browser I am getting an alert() function stating Error, which I have mentioned inside my code within function GetABC(PageIndex){}